# Please help me to Use Jpair

Tags: java, android

please I have need that you help me about using Jpair_v1.03 the bibliotheque. Because I don't understand how to he is working.

About Jpair

Jpair is a pure Java Implementation of bilinear pairing. It has no dependencies on external libraries. Although not fully tested, it should compatible with any Java version above 1.2. In fact, I've used it on the Android platform without changing any of the code.

The source for documentation:

https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/changyu.dong/jpair/jpair.html

I am sorry for my  bad level english

That is what i made but he doesn't work:

```
package jpair;
import uk.ac.ic.doc.jpair.api.Pairing;
import uk.ac.ic.doc.jpair.ibe.BFCipher;
import uk.ac.ic.doc.jpair.ibe.BFCtext;
import uk.ac.ic.doc.jpair.ibe.key.BFMasterPublicKey;
import uk.ac.ic.doc.jpair.ibe.key.BFUserPrivateKey;
import uk.ac.ic.doc.jpair.ibe.key.BFUserPublicKey;
import uk.ac.ic.doc.jpair.pairing.*;
import uk.ac.ic.doc.jpair.api.*;

import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.util.Random;


public class main {

public static void main(String[] args){
     System.out.println("debut");


    //using a predefined pairing
     Pairing e = Predefined.nssTate();

     //get P, which is a random point in group G1 
     Point P = e.RandomPointInG1(new Random());

     //get Q, which is a random point in group G2 
     Point Q = e.RandomPointInG2(new Random());


    //compute e(P,Q)
     FieldElement epq =e.compute(P,Q);

    //the curve on which G1 is defined 
     EllipticCurve g1 = e.getCurve();
    //a is a 160-bit random integer
    BigInt a = new BigInt(160,new Random()); 
    //Point aP is computed over G1
    Point aP = g1.multiply(P, a);


    //The curve on which G2 is defined
     EllipticCurve g2 = e.getCurve2();
    //b is a 160-bit random integer
    BigInt b = new BigInt(160,new Random());
    //bQ is computed over G2
    Point bQ = g2.multiply(Q, b);

    //compute e(aP,bQ)
     FieldElement res = e.compute(aP,bQ);

     //compute e(P,Q)^ab, this is done in group Gt
     BigInt ab = a.multiply(b);
     //get the field on which Gt is defined
     Field gt = e.getGt();
     FieldElement res2 = gt.pow(epq,ab); 

     //compare these two

     if(res.equals(res2))
     {
         System.out.println("Correct! e(aP,bQ) = e(P,Q)^ab");
     }
     else{
         System.out.println("Something is wrong! e(aP,BQ) != e(P,Q)^ab"); 
         }
     //debut du test -->

     java.security.KeyPair masterKey=BFCipher.setup( e ,new Random());
     System.out.println(masterKey);

     java.security.KeyPair pk=BFCipher.extract( masterKey,"Nabil",new Random());
     System.out.println(pk);

     byte msg[]= new byte[50];
     String s = "test message";
     msg = s.getBytes();


        BFMasterPublicKey sdf = new BFMasterPublicKey(e,  P, aP) ;
        BFUserPublicKey m = new BFUserPublicKey("Nabil",sdf);
        System.out.println();

        BFCtext i=BFCipher.encrypt( m, msg, new Random()) ;

        BFUserPrivateKey sk = new BFUserPrivateKey(aP,sdf) ;

        byte msgre[]=new byte[50];

        msgre=BFCipher.decrypt(i, sk) ;

        System.out.println(msgre);// I am don't understand why to decrypt he doesn't work. Please help

     for(int j=0 ; j<msgre.length ; j++)
            System.out.print((char)msgre[j]);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the parameters of encrypt() and decrypt() functions.

According to theory:

For encrypt(),
the first argument must be the User Public Key generated from the **extract phase**

And,

For decrypt(). the second argument must be the User Private key, again generated from the **extract phase**

Try the following code. It will work.

```
 /*
 * ENCRYPTION USING Jpair SCHEME
 * DONE ACCORDING IBE SCHEME
 */

package ibe;

import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.util.Random;
import uk.ac.ic.doc.jpair.api.*;
import uk.ac.ic.doc.jpair.ibe.*;
import uk.ac.ic.doc.jpair.ibe.key.*;
import uk.ac.ic.doc.jpair.pairing.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //  GENERATE PAIRING "e"
        Pairing e = Predefined.nssTate();

        // SETUP
        java.security.KeyPair masterKey=BFCipher.setup( e ,new Random());


        //  EXTRACT
        java.security.KeyPair userKey=BFCipher.extract( masterKey,"abcd",new Random());
        //"abcd" can be replaced with an ID for user
        PublicKey uPub = userKey.getPublic();       //to use in encrypt()
        PrivateKey uPri = userKey.getPrivate();     //to use in decrypt()

        //  ENCRYPT
        byte msgenc[]= new byte[50];
        String s = "test message";
        msgenc = s.getBytes();
        System.out.println("MESSAGE BEFORE ENCRYPTION : " + s);

        BFCtext msgCipher = BFCipher.encrypt((BFUserPublicKey) uPub,msgenc, new Random()) ;

        //  DECRYPT
        byte msgdec[]=new byte[50];
        msgdec=BFCipher.decrypt(msgCipher, (BFUserPrivateKey) uPri) ;
        System.out.println("AFTER DECRYPTION : " );
        // Printing message
        for(int j = 0; j < msgdec.length; j++) {
            System.out.print((char)msgdec[j]);
        }

    }



}
```

This will give output as :

MESSAGE BEFORE ENCRYPTION : test message
AFTER DECRYPTION : test message